# make session with array but value alway wrong

Tags: php, laravel

My function is:

```
static private function productLastViewed($request, $item){
    $product_viewed = session()->get('product_viewed');
    if (!$product_viewed){
       $product_viewed= [$item]; //grant item first to array
       session()->put('product_viewed', $product_viewed); //session for array
    }else{
        session()->push('product_viewed', $item); //push some item view to session array 
    }
    return session()->get('product_viewed'); //return array in session
}
```

the value always only 1 item

Please say for me what is wrong?

Comment: `the value always only 1 item` <-- can't work out what this means. What value? Where? What was passed in? etc etc.

Comment: "product_viewed" => array:1 [▼
    0 => 8
  ]<--- when i click on product id 8, if i click on product id 7 then value is: "product_viewed" => array:1 [▼
    0 => 7
  ]
i want, the value example:
"product_viewed" => array:1 [▼
    0 => 7,
    1 =>9,
    2 => 15,
    .......
  ]

Answer (score 1):

Hi you are using a variable rather than array. You can add something like this

```
static private function productLastViewed($request, $item)
{
    $product_viewed = session()->get('product_viewed');
    if (!$product_viewed)
    {
      $product_viewed[]= $item; //grant item first to array
      session()->put('product_viewed', $product_viewed); //session for array
    } 
    else
    {
     $product_viewed[]= $item;
     session()->push('product_viewed', $product_viewed); //push some item view to session array 
    }
    return session()->get('product_viewed'); //return array in session
```

}

Comment: The array value always 1 item :(

Comment: $product_viewed = session()->get('product_viewed');
var_dump($product_viewed); <- always NULL, Why? Someone help me.

Comment: your assignment is wrong. Please read carefully. And you should have $item.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it's work right now. Using var_dump value is right but dd() is wrong.

Comment: @WildgrassVN I hope this solution is helpfull for you.  So It is better if you mark it as answer and upvote this. Then it will helps many members.